# CUDA/pycuda - Implement GPU "map" function on a classical function with a vector of parameters

Tags: python, mapreduce, gpu, pycuda

I show you below an example of code using pycuda with "kernel" code included in itself (with `SourceModule`)

```
import pycuda
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import threading
import numpy

class GPUThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, number, some_array):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.number = number
    self.some_array = some_array

def run(self):
    self.dev = cuda.Device(self.number)
    self.ctx = self.dev.make_context()

    self.array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(some_array.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(self.array_gpu, some_array)

    test_kernel(self.array_gpu)
    print "successful exit from thread %d" % self.number
    self.ctx.pop()

    del self.array_gpu
    del self.ctx

def test_kernel(input_array_gpu):
mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void f(float * out, float * in)
    {
        int idx = threadIdx.x;
        out[idx] = in[idx] + 6;
    }
    """)
func = mod.get_function("f")

output_array = numpy.zeros((1,512))
output_array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(output_array.nbytes)

func(output_array_gpu,
      input_array_gpu,
      block=(512,1,1))
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(output_array, output_array_gpu)

return output_array

cuda.init()
some_array = numpy.ones((1,512), dtype=numpy.float32)
num = cuda.Device.count()

gpu_thread_list = []
for i in range(num):
gpu_thread = GPUThread(i, some_array)
gpu_thread.start()
gpu_thread_list.append(gpu_thread)
```

I would like to use the same method but instead of using a "kernel code", I would like to do multiple calls of a function which is external (not a function like "kernel code"), i.e a classical function defined in my main program and which takes in argument different parameters shared by all the main program. Is it possible ?

People who have practiced `Matlab` may know the function `arrayfun` where `B = arrayfun(func,A)` is a vector of results given by applying function `func`for each element of vector `A`.

Actually, it is a version of what is commonly called the `map` function: I would like to do the same but with GPU/pycuda version.

### Update 1

Sorry, I forgot from the beginning of my post to say what I call an extern and classical function. Here is below an example of function which is used in main section :

```
    def integ(I1):
        function_A = aux_fun_LU(way, ecs, I1[0], I1[1])
        integrale_A = 0.25*delta_x*delta_y*np.sum(function_A[0:-1, 0:-1] + function_A[1:, 0:-1] + function_A[0:-1, 1:] + function_A[1:, 1:])
         
    def g(): 
        for j in range(6*i, 6*i+6):
            for l in range(j, 6*i+6):
                yield j, l 
 
    ## applied integ function to g() generator.
    ## Here I a using simple map function (no parallelization)      
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      map(integ, g())
```

### Update 2

Maybe a solution would be to call the extern function from a kernel code, benefiting as well of the high GPU power of multiple calls on kernel code. But how to deal with the returned value of this extern function to get it back into main program?

### Update 3

Here is below what I have tried:

```
    # Class GPUThread             
    class GPUThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, number, some_array):
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.number = number
          self.some_array = some_array

        def run(self):
          self.dev = cuda.Device(self.number)
          self.ctx = self.dev.make_context()
          self.array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(some_array.nbytes)
          cuda.memcpy_htod(self.array_gpu, some_array)
          test_kernel(self.array_gpu)
          print "successful exit from thread %d" % self.number
          self.ctx.pop()

          del self.array_gpu
          del self.ctx

    def test_kernel(input_array_gpu):
        mod1 = SourceModule("""
        __device__ void integ1(int *I1)
        {
        function_A = aux_fun_LU(way, ecs, I1[0], I1[1]);
        integrale_A = 0.25*delta_x*delta_y*np.sum(function_A[0:-1, 0:-1] + function_A[1:, 0:-1] + function_A[0:-1, 1:] + function_A[1:, 1:]);
        }""")

        func1 = mod1.get_function("integ1")

        # Calling function
        func1(input_array_gpu)

    # Define couples (i,j) to build Fisher matrix      
    def g1():
        for j in range(6*i, 6*i+6):
            for l in range(j, 6*i+6):
                yield j, l

    # Cuda init
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      cuda.init()
      # Input gTotal lists
      some_array1 = np.array(list(g1()))
      print 'some_array1 = ', some_array1
      # Parameters for cuda
      num = cuda.Device.count()
      gpu_thread_list = []
      for i in range(num):
        gpu_thread = GPUThread(i, some_array1)
        #gpu_thread = GPUThread(i, eval("some_array"+str(j)))
        gpu_thread.start()
        gpu_thread_list.append(gpu_thread)
```

I get the following error at the execution:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/mike/anaconda2/envs/py2cuda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "Example_GPU.py", line 1232, in run
self.array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(some_array.nbytes)
NameError: global name 'some_array' is not defined`
```

I can't see what's wrong with the variable 'some_array' and the line
`self.array_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(some_array.nbytes)`

What can I try next?

Comment: your external function would have to be compiled as a device function, i think. but if you have that, you could just program a wrapper around that

Comment: I have read this several times and still have no idea what you are asking. What is a "classical function"? Are you trying to ask whether you can use PyCUDA to run an arbitrary Python function on the GPU?

Comment: @DanielBauer. Thanks, How could I compile my function as a device function ?

Comment: where you wrote `__global__` in you code, that defines a kernel. the qualifier `__device__` defines a basic function, but compiled for the GPU. So you would at least have to put your functions in such a code block

Comment: @DanielBauer Bauer . I think that at least, someone has understood my issue, maybe. So from what you are saying, I have just to use `__device__` in front of my function and compile normally ? Do you have an example or any documentation on this solution ? Regards

Comment: @talonmies.  Do you know maybe "map" function in Python or in javascript ? this is the same that I would like but I wonder if I could code it in a GPU way with Cuda ? a classical function is a function wich is not in the kernel code ( I used this term of "kernel code" from OpenCL, I am new to Cuda, sorry). The only way that I know to do this with python is to call g generator with `integ` function with `multiprocessing` python libray like this (with 8 threads) : `pool = mp.Pool(8) pool.map(integ, g()) pool.terminate()`.

Comment: @DanielBauer. I tried a solution in **UPDATE 3** but get a syntax error, could you see please where is the issue ? Regards

Comment: Seriously? How about putting the code in a string. we are not a free mistake spotting service. Please don't treat us like one

Comment: Sorry, error is human. I fixed it and put modif in UPDATE 3. This seem to work but I have got to do some other tests.

Comment: There is no way that works. You have a notionally CUDA C device function with *python* code inside it. That is never going to work. In PYCUDA all GPU code is always written in C.

Comment: @talonmies . So how could I call a function from CPU and execute it into GPU ? Have you got any examples ? Regards

Comment: You can't. That isn't possible in PyCUDA and why I asked the question about all of this "classical function" nonsense in your question in the first place

Comment: @talonmies So in my case, I can't call the following first call in my kernel : `function_A = aux_fun_LU(way, ecs, I1[0], I1[1]);`even syntax is the same into C and python ?

Comment: So I must conclude there is no way to optimize `map` calls of my python functions unless 1) I implement all these functions in C language to benefit from kernel code or 2) I use `pool.map` from python multiprocessing library ... it's a pity

Comment: Your latest error is because of a missing `self`. But leaving aside another trivial mistake, the entire premise of your question is impossible, and might I suggest that an hour reading some PyCUDA documentation would have made it clear that it is impossible, and you would have saved yourself and others a lot of wasted time, as well as needlessly wasting 50 rep on a pointless bounty

Comment: CUDA is like "mapping" 1D - 3D virtual grid points to a kernel function. It should be simple by implementing a "np" which has "sum" and other methods in the string literal and getting rid of bracketed range descriptors which CUDA/C++ doesn't understand. If you don't want to implement this yourself, then you'd use an already-made CUDA engine for Python(don't know if this exists) or hire a software developer to do this for you.